# Add typescript to express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to convert a javascript project to typescript and am able to run `npx tsc` with no errors, the output in dist is:

file init.ts

```
import message from './server'
console.log(message)
```

And server.ts: `export default 'hello word'`

Running npx tsc gives me the output:

```
import message from './server';
console.log(message);
```

And server is `export default 'hello word';`

When I run `node init.js` I get the error:

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'path/dist/server' imported from path/dist/init.js
> Did you mean to import ../server.js?

And when I change init.js to import `import message from './server.js';` it works. Why does typescript not do this?

In tsconfig I have target and module set to `ES2022`.

The package.json has a start command with `"start": "ts-node -r ./src/init.ts",` and this gives me the error: `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: path/src/init.ts`

Comment: When you use ECMAScript modules, you **must** specify the file extension.

Comment: Wait, if you add file extensions, **TypeScript** doesn't compile your code? That's quite odd since it certainly shouldn't mess with import paths (and also, works on my machine).

Comment: You're supposed to use the `js` file extension, even in the TypeScript file - again, TypeScript will not change import paths.

Comment: @caTS It's unintuitive because `server.js` does not exist but it did the trick. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, but `server.js` exists in the compiled output :)

Comment: @caTS The import from file.js' is working for compilatoin but ts-jest does not like it. If my tests import from a ts file with: `import something from 'file.js'` and file.js of course doesn't exist because it's file.ts I get the error: `cannot find module`, if the javascript file does exist then the error is: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` (file.js is an ESM and used import statements)

Comment: I usually have to use two tsconfigs - one for prod and one for testing - since testing frameworks like Jest and Mocha dislike ESM for some reason...